# How to decompose data from an array into labels in a table in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I get JSON from the site. I lay out the data in the model. From the model I load the data into the array "arrayOfMoney". How to put it into labels on the table now?

This is a model:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Valute: Decodable {
    let usd, eur, lkr: TypeCurrency
}

struct TypeCurrency: Decodable {

    let alphaCode: String
    let name: String
    let inverseRate: Double

}
```

Create properties:

```swift
    var arrayOfImage = ["USD","EUR","SGD","BYN","PLN","TRY","INR","KZT"]
    var arrayOfMoney = [Valute]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Next we get the data and fill the array "arrayOfMoney":

```swift
    private func fetchRequest() {

        guard let url = URL(string: Contents.urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

            do {

                let parseJson = try JSONDecoder().decode(Valute.self, from: data)
                self.arrayOfMoney.insert(parseJson, at: 0)

            } catch  let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }.resume()
    }
```

Now I am inserting data this way:

```swift
extension TableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOfMoney.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomizeCell
        configureCell(cell: cell, for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    private func configureCell(cell: CustomizeCell, for indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let currency = arrayOfMoney[indexPath.row]
        cell.charCodeLabel?.text = currency.usd.alphaCode
        cell.nameLabel?.text = currency.usd.name
        cell.valueTextField.text = "\(NSString(format:"%.2f", currency.usd.inverseRate))" 
        cell.imageViewPic.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImage[indexPath.row])
    }
```

But I need to insert all the currencies and I did not understand how to do this dynamically?

Thank you for your responses

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you have to declare `arrayOfMoney`

```
var arrayOfMoney = [TypeCurrency]()
```

and populate it

```
 let parseJson = try JSONDecoder().decode(Valute.self, from: data)
 self.arrayOfMoney = [parseJson.usd, parseJson.eur, parseJson.lkr]
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Then change `configureCell` to

```
private func configureCell(cell: CustomizeCell, for indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currency = arrayOfMoney[indexPath.row]
    cell.charCodeLabel?.text = currency.alphaCode
    cell.nameLabel?.text = currency.name
    cell.valueTextField.text = String(format:"%.2f", currency.inverseRate) // округляем до двух знаков после запятой
    cell.imageViewPic.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImage[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: I have an declared array, only its type "Valute"

Comment: `Valute` is a single object even if you declare it as array. You need the `TypeCurrency` properties joined as array as described in my answer.

Comment: It doesn’t work out according to your method. Writes a type error.
I added some more code here

Comment: I updated the answer. Please follow exactly my suggestion.

Comment: thank you very much!. Everything worked. Now I will think how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array of the object (which details show on table cell). Use this array in below data source method of `tableView`. You will get the IndexPath which will have the corresponding row. Which you can use to access respective data from array to show it on cell.

```
func configureCell(cell: CustomizeCell, for indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

Comment: array created. But I can’t fill all the data from it into a table. I have 50 currencies and I will have to create a manual cell for each currency in the table, but I want to dynamically

Comment: you can do dynamically as well, you need to have array one object for each row.